# Select - by ID of a group - in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query that **selects** several columns, **groups** and **assigns IDs** to those groups.
Now, my final step would be to **select a group by ID**. But for some reason it doesn't work.

```
select MYCOLUMN, 
   col2,
   sum(cal_a+col_b),
   col3,
   count(col4) as col4sum,
   DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY MYCOLUMN) GROUPID
from my_tab
group by  MYCOLUMN, col2, col3
where GROUPID = '2'
```

What could be wrong, how can I select my group 2?

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY...` correct order

Comment: Yes, that's useful, @lad2025. But still.. 
ORA-00904: "GROUPID": invalid identifier, 
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a subquery or CTE:

```
select t.*
from (select MYCOLUMN, col2, sum(cal_a+col_b), col3,
             count(col4) as col4sum,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MYCOLUMN) as GROUPID
      from my_tab
      group by MYCOLUMN, col2, col3
     ) t
where GROUPID = 2;
```

Don't use single quotes around integer constants.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.